# How can I access the Header of and ajax response from the rest API

Tags: ajax

How can I access the Header of and ajax response from the rest API?

I need the total number of pages (X-WP-TotalPages)

Here my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var pageCounter = 1;
  var ourHTMLString = '';



/////////////////////////////////////
// Ajax function starts            //
/////////////////////////////////////

  function llamadaAjax() {
    $.ajax({ //comienza ajax
    type: 'GET',
    url: magicalData.siteURL + '/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed&categories=5&page=' + pageCounter,
    success: function (articulos) {
    $.each(articulos, function (index, articulo) {
        ourHTMLString += '<article class="post">';
        ourHTMLString += '<div class="post-thumbnail fade1"><img src="' + articulo._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][0].media_details.sizes['small-thumbnail'].source_url + '"></div>';
        ourHTMLString += '<a href="' + articulo.link + '"><h3>' + articulo.title.rendered + '</h3></a>';
        ourHTMLString += '<p>' + articulo.content.rendered + '</p>';
        ourHTMLString += '</article>';

      }); 

      $('#criticasPostContainer').html(ourHTMLString);
    }
  }); 

  // fin ajax

}

///////////////////////////////
  // fin FUNCIÓN llamada ajax
///////////////////////////////


 llamadaAjax();

 // // click event listeners

$('button.botonSigCriticas').click(function(){
  pageCounter++;
  ourHTMLString = '';
  llamadaAjax();
  });

$('button.botonAntCriticas').click(function(){
  pageCounter--;
  ourHTMLString = '';
  llamadaAjax();
  });


  });// end jquery function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use change ajax this: `request.getResponseHeader('your_header')`

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url:'api-url.php',
    data: formData,
    success: function(data, textStatus, request){
        alert(request.getResponseHeader('your_header'));
    },
    error: function (request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(request.getResponseHeader('your_header'));
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand. Can you b more specific?
I dont have an error property, nor a post type, it's a GET.
If i add a third argument to my success property it returns a lot of info where i cannot find the X-WP-TotalPages